# Username and args connecting? \\ Discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

[image]

The `[text]` is being combined with the `[username]` (you can place any username where "`realdonaldtrump`" is. anything after that is the actual message.

I've tried numerous things, only thing I ever got to work was having trump being the default tweet and not being able to change it so it would've been `>tweet [message]` instead of `>tweet [username] [message]` but I'd like to have custom usernames. Any clue on how to remove the `[username]` from the `[text]`

**Here's the code**

```
exports.exec = async (client, message, args, level, settings, texts) => {

    const user = args[0];

    // Fires Error message that the command wasn't ran correctly.
    if (!user) {
        return client.emit('commandUsage', message, this.help);
    }
    // Fires Error message that the command wasn't ran correctly.

    const text = args.join(" ");

    // Below is a self-deletion message prior to image sending when it's fetching the actual image.
    message.channel.send({
        embed: {
            color: 0,
            description: `${message.author} Generating image.`
        }
    }).then(msg => {
        msg.delete(5000).catch(() => { });
    }).catch(e => {
    });
    // Above is a self-deletion message prior to image sending when it's fetching the actual image.

    try {
        const { body } = await snekfetch.get(`https://nekobot.xyz/api/imagegen?type=${user.toLowerCase() === "realdonaldtrump" ? "trumptweet" : "tweet"}&username=${user.startsWith("@") ? user.slice(1) : user}&text=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`);
        message.channel.send("", { file: body.message });

        // Below is a automatic logger
    } catch (err) {
        const errorlogs = client.channels.get('480735959944527886')
        const embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor("ERROR", "https://i.imgur.com/Omg7uJV.png")
            .setDescription(`${message.author} An error has occured using this command, this has automatically be logged and sent to ${client.channels.get('480735959944527886')} to be reviewed.`)
            .setColor(0)
            .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send({ embed });
        errorlogs.send(`Error with \`$tweet\` command!\n\nError:\n\n ${err}`)
    }
    // Above is a automatic logger
};
```

Comment: Could you show us the whole code. You are using await, but were is the async part?

Comment: Apologies for that, re-edited the code block to have the whole code except for the export options as they all work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are concatenating your `args` to set your `text` variable

```
const text = args.join(" ");
```

But as `args` value is `["realdonaltrump", "yeeet"]` in your example, it results in `text` having the value `"realdonaldtrump yeet"`.

Just do as you did for the `user`variable:

```
const text = args[1]
```

You might need to validate the value of the argument.

Comment: Wow. I spent over an hour staring at this, I had `const text = args[0]` at a stage. Can't believe it was just this.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.replace` method and it will replace the username with nothing:

```
const text = args.join(" ").replace(new RegExp(`${user}`), "")
```

Hope it helps!!!